# Concat two columns and columns are obtained via SELECT queries

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I need help with CONCAT function. I have two select queries and the result of every query is one column. I need to merge this two columns in one. Is that possible? Beacuse, I can't get result even if I try with simple select queries like:

```
SELECT owner FROM table WHERE number="value1";
SELECT number FROM table WHERE owner="value2" AND number IS NOT null;
```

These queries work and throw 3 rows like result. But, if I want to merge them in one column using CONCAT - that doesn't work. Do you know why?

```
SELECT CONCAT(SELECT owner FROM table WHERE number="value1",
SELECT number FROM table WHERE owner="value2" AND number IS NOT null
) as NEW_COLUMN FROM table;
```

Comment: Why do you have "FROM table" at the end?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(owner, number) newCol1
FROM yourTable
WHERE number="value1"
    OR (owner="value2" AND number IS NOT null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   CONCAT(owner, number) as NEW_COLUMN
FROM
   table
WHERE
   owner = "value2"
   AND number = "value1"
   AND number IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental reason is that the DB cannot concatenate two different SELECTs which might have a different number of rows.

What you need to do is to re-formulate your query in terms of a JOIN.

For example suppose we have this table:

```
owner    number
John     value1
value2   123456
```

Your first query:

```
SELECT owner FROM table WHERE number="value1";
```

will return "John". The second one

```
SELECT number FROM table WHERE owner="value2" AND number IS NOT null;
```

will return "123456".

If you CONCAT the two values you would therefore get "John 123456".

First of all, is this the expected behaviour of the query you want? What happens is there is a third row with owner=Jack and number=value1, so that the first query returns TWO rows "John" and "Jack"?

One thing you could look into is the `CROSS JOIN` syntax.

```
SELECT CONCAT (table1.owner, ', ', table2.number) AS new_column
     FROM ( SELECT owner FROM table WHERE number="value1" ) AS tablel1
     CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT number FROM table WHERE owner="value2" AND number IS NOT null ) AS table2;
```

Note that if the first query returns three rows and the second four rows, the combined query will return 3*4 = 12 rows.